# docx4j how to insert image into table cell

Tags: docx4j

I can't insert image into table cell using docx4j using following code:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(PageSizePaper.A4,true);
ObjectFactory factory=Context.getWmlObjectFactory();Tbl table = factory.createTbl();
Tr tableRow = factory.createTr();    
byte[] imageBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(t.getBase64Image());
BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(wordPackage, imageBytes);
Inline inline = imagePart.createImageInline("image", "image", 0, 1, false);

P celPar = addInlineImageToParagraph(inline, factory);

Tc tableCell = factory.createTc();
tableCell.getContent().clear();
tableCell.getContent().add(celPar);
tableRow.getContent().add(tableCell); 
wordPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(table);


private P addInlineImageToParagraph(Inline inline, ObjectFactory factory) {
    P paragraph = factory.createP();
    R run = factory.createR();
    paragraph.getContent().add(run);
    Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();
    run.getContent().add(drawing);
    drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);
    return paragraph;
}
```

Word has problem displaying image. I realy don't know where's problem

Answer (score 0):

If you looked at a docx resulting from your code, you would see:

```
<w:tbl></w:tbl>
```

You are just missing

```
table.getContent().add(tableRow);
```

**EDIT 24 Sept**

You didn't say you until now that you were trying to add your image in a footer!

For this you need to specify that part, so the rel attaches to the footer.  So use https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/BinaryPartAbstractImage.java#L247 or https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/BinaryPartAbstractImage.java#L339 etc ie one of the signatures which contains Part sourcePart

Comment: JasonPlutext, thank you, I've just fix it but docx document is generated but still when I try to open it I get warning about missing content in /word/document.xml. Table is visible but there is no image. I can only see its rectangle with info about bad content. My image is corrrect - when I add paragraph which I create in addInlineImageToParagraph method to mainPart everything is OK.

Comment: Then I guess your problem is Base64.getDecoder().decode(t.getBase64Image()); is making a corrupt image.  Your code works for me apart from that line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hmm... I'm not sure if the problem is in image generation. As i said when I add paragraph created in addInlineImageToParagraph method to mainpart of document my image is visible and properly rendered.

Comment: ok sorry, missed that.  Can you post your document somewhere?

Comment: Of course... May I send it on "jason at plutext dot org" (I hope it's your address) :)

Comment: @AdalbertSeptember sure

Comment: Hmm... I've sent email on "jason at plutext dot org" with attached docx file. Maybe I should send it with zip attachement?

Comment: no, still nothing, and its not in my spam folder.  can you post it somewhere?  you could do that in the docx4j forum..

Comment: I think problem is with my email account, I've tried from another... Hope this time will be OK - message sent again...

Comment: thank you, thank you very, very much. Now it works great. I'm sorry that I missed key info. Life is wonderful again :))